# how to Add integers from two different fragments into one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio-2.3

i'm just new to android studio and I have this problem. In my Tab1(1st fragment) i have Checkboxes that when you select, it will add a value to Total(fragment where i sent all value) and it works just fine.

[image]

And then when I select a Checkbox in my Tab2(2nd fragment), the value will not add. In short each fragment has its total value.

[image]

Now how can i add it all?

heres my Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    CheckBox mc1,mc2,mc3,mc4,mc5,mc6,mc7,mc8,mc9,mc10,mc11,mc12;
    communicator comm;
    int total;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        mc1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc1);
        mc1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc2);
        mc2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc3);
        mc3.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc4=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc4);
        mc4.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc5=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc5);
        mc5.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc6=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc6);
        mc6.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc7=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc7);
        mc7.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc8=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc8);
        mc8.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc9=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc9);
        mc9.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc10=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc10);
        mc10.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc11=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc11);
        mc11.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc12=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc12);
        mc12.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.mc1:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc2:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc3:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+350;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-350;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc4:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc5:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc6:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc7:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc8:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+200;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-200;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc9:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc10:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc11:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+450;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-450;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc12:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+550;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-550;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

heres my Tab2:

```
public class Tab2 extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    CheckBox aoc1,aoc2,aoc3,aoc4;
    communicator comm;
    int total;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        aoc1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc1);
        aoc1.setOnClickListener(this);
        aoc2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc2);
        aoc2.setOnClickListener(this);
        aoc3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc3);
        aoc3.setOnClickListener(this);
        aoc4=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc4);
        aoc4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.aoc1:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.aoc2:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.aoc3:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.aoc4:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my Total:

```
public class Total extends Fragment {
    TextView ttl;

    public Total() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.total, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ttl= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.total);
    }

}
```

and here's my `respond` in my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
    public void respond(String data) {
        ttl.setText(data);
    }
```

NOTE: my Total Fragment is in my activity_main, that's why it's just floating so when i change tab it doesn't move.

Comment: do not make calculation in each tab, just pass selected checkbox value to main fragment. in that fragment make calculation, you get correct value

Comment: How can i do that sir? i'm confused right now because i tried to make public int but it does'n work :(

Comment: first make int total in main fragment. now in each tab when you select checkbox pass comm.respond("50"); value.  and in main fragment make total + 50 and then set text(). same as when uncheck box pass comm.respond("-50");

Comment: should i put the int in public void respond(...)? or right after public class Main....? sorry i'm just newbie

Comment: int total; in total fragment's after extend Fragment{

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are creating `int total` seperately in your two tabs..you should keep it common..
Do something like this..

```
public Class CommonTotal{

private int total = 0;

   public int getTotal() {
      return total;
   } 
   public void setTotal(int total) {
      this.total = this.total + total ;
   }
}
```

create object of CommonTotal

```
CommonTotal commonTotal = new CommonTotal();
```

and refer it in your two tabs and instead of `int total`
Instead of doing like

```
case R.id.aoc1:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
```

Do something like this

```
case R.id.aoc1:
                if (checked) {
                    commonTotal.setTotal(50);//
                    //total = total + 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
```

Use MVC pattern..sorry for the typo. try to make some sense out of it.
Hope i gave you some idea.. If that helped mark me up :)
OR 
Simply create two methods in your MainActivity and a `public int total`

```
public void commonTotal(int t){
 total = total +t;
}

public void whatsthetotal(){
return total;
}
```

and call this method

Comment: where should i put public class common.... and the object? my mind gonna blow as a newbie

Comment: create a new Class as CommonTotal....Inside both of your fragments, Instead of creating total integer...create CommonTotal's object and wherever you are doing "total = total + your_num", call commonTotal.saveTotal(your_num)

Comment: i used your first suggestion but the out put is different. it just says the address maybe.

Comment: can u show me your entire code on github or something

Comment: what is github sir?